# Почему break и case '2' выдается ошибками?

Tags: c++

```
 #include <cstdlib>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <windows.h>
 #include <conio.h>
 #include <stdio.h>

 using namespace std;

 int main()
 {  char v='y';
 do   
 {
 cout << "1. Copy File" << endl;
 cout << "2. Move File" << endl;
 cout << "3. Rename File" << endl;
 cout << "4. Delete File" << endl;
 cout << "5. Format Disc" << endl;
 cout << "6. Search" << endl;
 cout << "7. Clear Cash" << endl;
 cout << "8. Download File\n" << endl;

 v=getch();
 switch(v)

 { case '1':
 cout << "Copy File Function\n" << endl;

 char path1[100], path2[100];
 cout << ">> Type First Adress <<" << endl;
 cin >> (path1);
 cout << endl;
 cout << ">> Type Second Adress <<" << endl;
 cin >> (path2);

 CopyFile(path1,path2, true);
 cout << endl;
 cout << " File is Copied\n " << endl ; 
 cout << " Do you want to continue? (Y/N)? " << endl;
 cin >> v;

 if (v=='y') system("cls");
 while (v != 'n');
 break;

 case '2':

 cout << "Copy File Function\n" << endl;

 char path3[100], path4[100];
 cout << ">> Type First Adress <<" << endl;
 cin >> (path1);
 cout << endl;
 cout << ">> Type Second Adress <<" << endl;
 cin >> (path2);

 MoveFile(path3,path4, true);
 cout << endl;
 cout << " File is Copied\n " << endl ; 
 cout << " Do you want to continue? (Y/N)? " << endl;
 cin >> v;

 if (v=='y') system("cls");     
 while (v != 'n');
 }
 system("PAUSE"); 
 } while(true);
 }
```

хочу слить 2 процесса в одно, с помощь switch, я прочитал про него, но ошибки выдает, поможете мне разобраться? хочу переключаться между операциями 1 и 2

Comment: Код бы не помешало отформатировать.

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку остались мелочи, пишу окончательный вариант (все что закомментировано можно удалить):

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
//#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char v/*='y'*/;
    char path1[100], path2[100];
    do
    {
        cout << "1. Copy File" << endl;
        cout << "2. Move File" << endl;
        cout << "3. Rename File" << endl;
        cout << "4. Delete File" << endl;
        cout << "5. Format Disc" << endl;
        cout << "6. Search" << endl;
        cout << "7. Clear Cash" << endl;
        cout << "8. Download File\n" << endl;

        v=getch();
        switch(v)
        {
            case '1':
                cout << "Copy File Function\n" << endl;

                // char path1[100], path2[100];
                cout << ">> Type First Adress <<" << endl;
                cin >> (path1);
                cout << endl;
                cout << ">> Type Second Adress <<" << endl;
                cin >> (path2);

                CopyFile(path1,path2, true);
                cout << endl;
                cout << " File is Copied\n " << endl ; 
                /*cout << endl;
                cout << " File is Copied\n " << endl ; 
                cout << " Do you want to continue? (Y/N)? " << endl;
                cin >> v;

                if (v=='y') system("cls");
                while (v != 'n');*/
                break;

            case '2':
                cout << "Move File Function\n" << endl;

                // char path1[100], path2[100];
                cout << ">> Type First Adress <<" << endl;
                cin >> (path1);
                cout << endl;
                cout << ">> Type Second Adress <<" << endl;
                cin >> (path2);

                MoveFile(path1,path2);
                cout << endl;
                cout << " File is Copied\n " << endl ; 
        }
        cout << " Do you want to continue? (Y/N)? " << endl;
        cin >> v;
        if (v=='y') system("cls");
    } while (v != 'n');

    system("PAUSE"); 
}
```

Я поменял `while(true)` на твой `while(v!='n')`, который стоял внутри `switch` (причем два раза), а должен был быть снаружи. Цикл `while(true)` никогда бы не закончился, если конечно не использовать `break`.

Подправил фигурные скобки, их должно быть одинаковое количество открытых и закрытых (и они должны быть правильно вложены друг в друга).

`char path1[100], path2[100];` перенес в самое начало функции `main`.

Убрал параметр `true` в вызове функции `MoveFile(path1,path2);`

Одинаковые окончания блоков `case` вынес из `switch`.

Структура программы была примерно такой:

```
void main()
{
do
{
switch(v)
{
case '1':
while(...); // while должен быть снаружи switch и перед ним дожна быть закр. скобка.
break;
case '2':
while(...); // второй вайл туда же
}
```

А стала вот такой:

```
void main()
{
do
{
switch(v)
{
case '1':
break;
case '2':
}
} while(...); // скобка в этой строке соответствует скобке после do (закрывает ее)
}
```

Обрати внимание на количество открытых и закрытых скобок.

Comment: Сравни этот вариант со своим, у меня ничего не "замораживается"
P.S. У тебя скорее всего перед while(v != 'n') нет фигурной скобки

Comment: спасибо! можешь мне объяснить, что ты сделал, точнее изменил? например ты while(true); убрал, а какую роль он играл? ну и в общем, что ты сделал что она там начала работать, если не трудно, коротко скажи, я пойму )

Comment: @navi1893, если ответ помог, прими его:)

Comment: а как принимать то? что это означает?

Comment: См. [Справка - ХэшКод](http://hashcode.ru/faq/), "как принять ответ". Видимо должна быть специальная кнопка рядом с голосовалкой за ответ:)

Answer (score 0):

по-моему ты просто со скобками напутал :)

Comment: у тебя после if (v=='y') system("cls"); закрывается switch, а затем do.
вот он и жалуется на case и break

Comment: а чтобы не ошибаться в положении скобок, нужно использовать отступы

Comment: 1. По-моему все равно скобки не правильно расствлены, в свитче должно быть так:

    switch(v)
    {
    case '1':
    // ...
    break;
    case '2':
    // ...
    }

2. Зачем MoveFile третий параметр? Он принимает всего два, вот и ругается.
3. Что делает эта строка while (v != 'n'); ?

Comment: `MoveFile(path1,path2, true);`
true - это третий параметр, которого у MoveFile быть не должно

while (v != 'n'); а где он в этом цикле считывает с клавиатуры? Подчеркиваю, эта строка целиком является циклом.

Comment: Уже лучше. У тебя последняя скобка закрывает только switch, а еще нужно закрыть скобку цикла, поставить while с каким-нибудь условием) и закрыть скобку мейна

Comment: все сработало, спасибо! но, я выбираю 2(Move) он выводит, ввожу все отлично, потом он у меня просит продолжить (y/n), я нажимаю y-^ enter он зачищает при этом экран и только! не выводит повторно меню, при том он замораживается на чистом экране и я даже не могу там что-то ввести

Comment: См. ответ. Прошу обратить внимание на отступы, они не только делают код красивым, но и более читаемым

Answer (score 0):

После

```
case '1': 
    cout << "Copy File Function\n" << endl;
```

нужно просто добавить

```
do 
{
}
```

и в цикле `do` должны быть все строки от `char path1[100]`, pat`h2[100];` до `while (v != 'n');`

и в итоге должно получится примерно так:

```
int main() 
{
    // ...
    do
    {
        // ...
        switch(v)
        {
            case '1'
                do
                {
                }
                while(v != 'n')
                break
            case '2'
                do
                {
                }
                while(v != 'n')
                break
        } // здесь сейчас заканчивается твоя программа, а нужно еще:
    } while(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В блоках switch нельзя объявлять переменные. Если взять участки кода от case до break в фигурные скобки, то будет работать.